# Show $(⊕M_α)/I(⊕M_α)\simeq ⊕(M_α/IM_α)$ for ${M_α}$ $R$-modules, and $I$ is an ideal of the commutative ring $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ideals, direct-sum

Let $(M_α)$ be a collection of $R$-modules, and $I$ is an ideal of the commutative ring $R$. Show that $(⊕M_α)/I(⊕M_α)$ is isomorphic to $⊕(M_α/IM_α)$ as $R/I$-modules.

Please help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without tensor products

The obvious $R-$homomorphism
$$
f:\oplus M_\alpha \rightarrow \oplus(M_\alpha/IM_\alpha)
$$
is surjective and clearly satisfies
$$
I(\oplus M_\alpha) \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(f)
$$
so you have to prove the other inclusion, a fun exercise (not trivial!)

Once you have this, it is easy to show that the resulting $R-$isomorphism is $R/I$-linear.

Comment: thank yo for answering, may I ask if the way to show the last step is the 1st isomorphism theorem?

Comment: I think I know my above answer now. thank you. but can you give some hints for the not trivial step, the other inclusion. thanks.

Comment: Do not show the other inclusion by hand: Once you know $I(\oplus M_\alpha)$ lies in the kernel, you get a map $$\oplus M_\alpha / I(\oplus M_\alpha) \to \oplus (M_\alpha/IM_\alpha)$$. It is very easy to give the inverse map, since giving map out of a direct sum is easy by the universal property.

Answer (score 3):

The tensor product commutes with arbitrary direct sums. Note that $M/IM = M \otimes R/I$